# How to show activity indicator inside the YouTube video frame?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, youtube

In my app I'm embedding a YouTube videos using this code:

```
- (void)playVideo:(NSString *)urlString frame:  (CGRect)frame
{

NSString *embedHTML = @"<body style=\"margin:0\"> <iframe height=\"110\" width=\"110\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/video id\" frameborder=\"0\"/></iframe> </body> ";


NSString *html = [NSString stringWithFormat:embedHTML, urlString, frame.size.width, frame.size.height];
UIWebView *videoView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];


[videoView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
[self.scrollView addSubview:videoView];
[videoView release];
NSLog(@"%@",html);

}
```

and in the viewWillAppear method:

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

[self playVideo:@"http://www.youtube.com/watch?video id" frame:CGRectMake(5, 20, 110, 110)];

}
```

But when my view loads it takes a while till my videos show up which could make the users feel that nothing happens , so I want to show an activity indicator inside these frames.
Can you guys help me with that ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See how you're adding "`videoView`" to your scroll view?  Why not add an "`UIActivityIndicator`" view as a subview either to your videoView or to your scrollView in a similar fashion?

Make sure to keep a handle / outlet to that activity indicator and remove it when the video starts to play.

Comment: I have tried your idea with the if statement but I'm not sure what code to put inside the two brackets () after the if.can you please give me a code that can help in my case. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see an "`if`" statement in your code currently displayed in your question. Could you edit your question to show what you are talking about within your implementation (source code)?

Comment: This what actually I was thinking to do I mean the if statement but I don't actually add it because as I said I'm not sure what code I need to put inside the two brackets. But I can tell you what I want to do : if the webView is not loaded show the activity indicator , else hide the activity indicator. Something like this.

Answer (score 0):

For Use `UIWebview` Better Performance use this way

in `ViewController.h` file

First SET `UIWebViewDelegate` As delegate

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UIWebViewDelegate> {

        UIWebView *videoView;
}
```

Just `override` all these methods into your `ViewController.m` file

```
– webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:
– webViewDidStartLoad:
– webViewDidFinishLoad:
– webView:didFailLoadWithError:
```

write your code display Activity indicator code Accordingly show your indicator

for more detail refer This [Link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

**EDIT:**

1. To Display & start Animation of Activityindicator in `– webViewDidStartLoad:` Method
2. stop Animation of Activityindicator in `– webViewDidFinishLoad:` Method
3. Dont forget to Set `Delegate`.